# "Out of memory" when I run a rake command on dotcloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dotcloud

I'm trying to host a website on dotcloud. In my postinstall file I have this :

```
cd /home/dotcloud/current && bundle exec rake db:migrate
cd /home/dotcloud/current && bundle exec rake db:seed
```

When it run a command I have this message :

> ./postinstall: line 1:   158 Killed                  bundle exec rake db:migrate

It's the same think with every rake commands.

My application is a normal live application and have 64mb reserved. When I see the memory usage I have this :[image]

At the bottom, there is dots which mark a "out of memory" error but all the memory is not used.

It works on sandbox.

So, is it possible to use dotcloud with the basic plan for a rails application? What can I do?

Comment: If you add more RAM to your application, do the OOM errors go away?

Comment: It works on the sandbox because if I remember correctly the sandbox starts off at 512MB of RAM, but you can't increase it at all. If you look at the dashboard charts for your application running on the sandbox, you can see what the normal RAM usage is, and make sure you leave enough head room so it can grow without OOM'ing

Answer (score 0):

I run this command and It works!

> dotcloud scale www:memory=128mb

Does it meens than a rails application does not work with 64mb of memory? Is there as way to do it?

Comment: I'm sure some Rails applications could run with 64MB of memory, but it looks like the one you are trying to run can't. It might not need the RAM all of the time, but if there are spikes it could run out of RAM fast.